# Get name of current animation state

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I get the name of the current state in a layer on my Animator component? I realize that I can compare the name with `GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("statename")` but I don't want to have to run that for each state in my layer. Is it possible to simply get the name of the current state?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can get the current playing clip name in the layer using following code

```
private Animator animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
private AnimatorClipInfo[] clipInfo;

public string GetCurrentClipName(){
    int layerIndex = 0;
    clipInfo = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo(layerIndex); 
    return clipInfo[0].clip.name;
}
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer I can find for this simple problem.  Thank you!

Comment: This will return the clip name, not the state name?

Answer (score 11):

I don't think this was possible. The only good solution I can think about is to use `switch` statement and `nameHash` like this:

```
Animator animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

// Get the id of all state for this object
int runId = Animator.StringToHash("Run");
int jumpId = Animator.StringToHash("Jump");

AnimatorStateInfo animStateInfo = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);

switch (animStateInfo.nameHash)
{
    case runId:
        Debug.Log("Current state is Run");
        break;
    case jumpId:
        Debug.Log("Current state is Jump");
        break;
    default:
        Debug.Log("Current state is not in this list");
        break;
}
```

Comment: This is the best aproach. But getting the name is possible by Reflection I quess. But it would be very expensive aproach.

Answer (score -1):

Using `AnimatorStateInfo.IsName(string name)`.

```
AnimatorStateInfo asi = GetComponent<Animator>().GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);
if(asi.IsName("Animation State Name"))
{
    // Playing "Animation State Name" now.
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Let me tell you now: this is impossible. See those hundreds of tabs you have open? None of them have the answer, because you cannot get the name of a state. Period.

But all is not lost, developer, you're savvy. You know there are workarounds.

```
AnimationClip[] clips = anim.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips; //this gets all your clips in your animator. ALL.
for (int i = 0; i < clips.Length; i++){
    print(clips[i].name); //you should create a list to store all of these.
}
Animator _aci = GetComponent<Animator>().GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo(0);
List<theClassYouMadeForYourList> theListYouMade = new List <theClassYouMadeForYourList>(); //make sure you make a class for your list "theClassYouMadeForYourList"
for(int i = 0; i < theListYouMade.Count; i++){
    if(theListYouMade[i] == _aci[0].clip.name){//is the list item equal to the current clip name? Then do something
        print("doing something");
        break;
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work. ;)